# How to create a voronoi diagram inside a circle with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geometry, voronoi

I quite like [this graphic by NYtimes](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2008/05/03/business/20080403_SPENDING_GRAPHIC.html?_r=0). This one I think is created with illustrator but would it be possible to create something like this with d3.js? Is there a working example of this somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure your example is a [Voronoï diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)? What would be the distance (between what and what)? And what kind of distance would it be?

Comment: I certainly looks like voronoi, but I am not sure, I am just wondering would it be possible to create something like this with d3

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a voronoi treemap. It is created by recursively subdivide the area with a weighted voronoi diagram:https://www.jasondavies.com/voronoi-treemap/. For instance you can substract the weight from the euclidian distance and skipping overlapping points.

Comment: I see https://www.jasondavies.com/voronoi-treemap/ is a good sample, but not sure how make the animation. Do you know?

Comment: No. You could take look at the 1st frame of the video and then the last frame. I don't know the meaning. You could try my weighted voronoi diagram at https://awvd.codeplex.com!